# Xcode - is it possible to group breakpoints?

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I'd like to group my breakpoints in something like group 1, group 2, and be able to activate / deactivate groups simply, without adding / removing everything. I know how to toggle all breakpoints on/off.

My use case is the following: group 2 contains breakpoints that are hit very often, but I'm only interested in them after an event in group 1 occurs. So I'd like to run my app with group 1 on and group 2 off, and when group 1 is hit, turn group 2 on. I don't want to press play hundreds of times for events that happen in group 2 before group 1 is hit, and I don't want to readd all breakpoints in group 2 after group 1 is hit, and remove all of them at the end of the session.

Currently, I'm putting all my breakpoints in group 2 in something like:

```
if globalFlag {
    print("group 2 breakpoint")
}
```

and I'm setting `globalFlag` to `true` when group 1 is hit, and putting breakpoints within the condition.

Is there's a better way?

Comment: Very much want the same.    It seems like such an obvious feature for anybody working on a non-trivial system.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can do this using the -N (Name) command.  I've been debugging some non trivial code and it would be very useful to enable certain groups of breakpoints at different stages of debugging.
I ran across this blog entry that seems to confirm:  https://volonbolon-blog.tumblr.com/post/126507197542/grouping-breakpoints

Once you've named your breakpoints you and enable, disable and delete each group by using the name you've specified.